# How do you play a sound file without opening any media players?

Tags: python, windows, python-2.7, audio

I'm writing a simple script that I would like to have notify me of an event with a sound file on my computer.

While I can play a sound file by doing something like:

```
import webbrowser
webbrowser.open("C:\Users\User\Desktop\Test\Test.mp3")
```

That will open up VLC or whatever media player I have, which could alt-tab me / interfere with whatever I was doing.

Is there a way to play the sound file without anything popping up? A perfect example of what I am looking to do would be using something like making a beep sound using winsound as such:

```
import winsound
Freq = 600 # Set Frequency To 600 Hertz
Dur = 800 # Set Duration To 800 ms == 0.8 second(s)
winsound.Beep(Freq,Dur)
```

Which makes a quick beeping sound without opening any new windows.

Comment: What exactly is the problem if winsound is working for you?

Comment: I've never used it but [pyaudio](https://people.csail.mit.edu/hubert/pyaudio/docs/#) may work for you.

Comment: @Achilles - OP wants to play an mp3 file. Right now he does it by bringing up a browser but he wants something more backgroundy.

Comment: @Achilles I'd just rather hear a pleasant sound file for my notification than an unenjoyable beep. If I can't find an answer then I'll use the beep, but I figured it couldn't hurt to ask and maybe learn something new I didn't have find much luck in finding for myself.

Comment: For Windows, if you convert the MP3 to WAV, you can simply use `winsound.PlaySound(wav_path, winsound.SND_FILENAME | winsound.SND_ASYNC)`.

Comment: Windows can also play the MP3, but you'll need to use ctypes to call [`mciSendString`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd757161). For example: `import ctypes;` `winmm = ctypes.WinDLL('winmm');` `winmm.mciSendStringW(r'open "%s" type mpegvideo alias "%s"' % (path, alias), None, 0, None);` `winmm.mciSendStringW('play "%s"' % alias, None, 0, None)`. Then to quit playing and close the song: `winmm.mciSendStringW('close "%s"' % alias, None, 0, None).`

Comment: @eryksun Thank you so much, that worked great

Answer (score 2):

This does the trick. 
Firstly, install pyglet:

```
pip install pyglet
```

Now download and install [AVbin from here](http://avbin.github.io/AVbin/Download.html)
Do check where AVbin is installed as now you have to go to the installation directory and copy the avbin.dll to the directory where you saved your code.

Finally,run this code:

```
import pyglet
pyglet.lib.load_library('avbin')
pyglet.have_avbin=True
song = pyglet.media.load('filename.mp3')#your file name
song.play()
pyglet.app.run()
```

Make sure your music file is in the same directory as your code .py file.
Did this from my experience and it worked.

Answer (score 0):

Solved by @eryksun in the comments with the solution of:

```
winsound.PlaySound(wav_path, winsound.SND_FILENAME | winsound.SND_ASYNC)
```

This was the best solution for I've seen for what I was looking for. It uses default libraries, only takes up a single straight-forward line, and does what I need it to.

Answer (score 0):

You should use pygame to solve it

```py
def music(music):
    pygame.mixer.init()
    pygame.mixer.music.load(music)
    pygame.mixer.music.play()
```

it will play sound without opening vlc media player

search google for more otherwise this will be enough to know